# registerDoParallel() for function within function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I would like to perform parallel computing for functions inside a function. Psuedo-code is given below:

```
numCores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(numCores-1)  
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl) 

clusterExport(cl, c("necessary parameters")
clusterEvalQ(cl, source("other_functions.R")) 

pbapply::pblapply(1:n, function(...) {
    para <- function1(...)
}, cl = cl)

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Within function1(), I am calling some other functions from the "other_function.R" file. I would like to make the these functions parallel as well, but have been into the error, cannot find "cl". Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt this will work, since you are assigning numCores^2 cores with it. Please update your question with real code of a small example, rather than pseudo code.

Comment: @jay.sf You are right, this seems to be a problem of parallel nested functions. I decided to use Rcpp to speed up code instead of trying this approach in the end.

Comment: This sounds like a splendid idea!